# Postgres CREATE/DROP DATABASE sometimes cause a syntax error

Tags: postgresql

I sometimes get syntax error at or near the commands, but the next try it works fine.

DROP DATABASE:

```
Superman-# DROP DATABASE a;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DROP"
LINE 2: DROP DATABASE a;
        ^
Superman=# DROP DATABASE a;
DROP DATABASE
```

and also the CREAT DATABASE:

```
Superman=# CREATE DATABSE task1database;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DATABSE"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABSE task1database;
           ^
Superman=# CREATE DATABASE a;
CREATE DATABASE
Superman=# CREATE DATABASE task1database;
CREATE DATABASE
```

Comment: `DATABSE` in your second example in the error message should tell you something. Does `DATABSE` look right?

Comment: Maybe you didn't finish the previous line correctly, like forgetting a semicolon?

Answer (score 8):

Observe the prompt in the first line:

```
Superman-#
```

The `-` is a sign that this is a continuation line, that is, you didn't finish whatever you wrote on the previous line with a semicolon.

The resulting SQL statement that is sent to the server is everything since the last semicolon, so the `DROP DATABASE` is somewhere in the middle of the string and causes a syntax error.

Always observe the prompt, and if it does not contain a `=`, you can clear the buffer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

The second example is just a typo in `DATABSE`.

Comment: I find the default prompts too subtle in `psql`. I use `\set PROMPT2 '...> '` to make the "continuation line" be way more obvious.